# ReactJs - Duplicate components without lagging the webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

In my app, I have one component like this. In the gray box, the user can enter two values. In here green color number means how many time those two values will repeat.

[image]

If the user entered 30000 as a repeat number, the webpage will freeze for 20-25 seconds. Because I'm looping the same component over 30000 times and appending it. Is there any solution to reduce freeze time or stop that freeze? I tried `React.lazy` but I'm getting `Objects can't be child elements` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need virtual scroll, virtual scroll keeps only visible elements on the DOM, have a look at the below link
https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider the more light weight, react-window from the same author!
https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window#how-is-react-window-different-from-react-virtualized

Comment: Thank you so much. your answer sold some issues I had with @user3597009. I'm marking his answer as a correct answer because that's the first answer I got.

Comment: Sure no worries! :)